# Error when using groovy-eclipse-plugin and @Grab

Tags: maven, groovy, groovy-grape

Getting the following error when running `mvn clean compile` on a new system. It works fine on my local (windows) environment.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project visa-threatintel: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /path/to/Class.groovy:[2,2] 1. ERROR in /path/to/Class.groovy (at line 2)
[ERROR] @Grab(group="javax.mail", module="mail", version="1.5.0-b01", type="jar"),
[ERROR] ^^^
[ERROR] Groovy:Ambiguous method overloading for method org.apache.ivy.core.settings.IvySettings#load.
```

Both local and new system use Maven 3.2.5 and the POM is identical. Relevant excerpts below:

```
<groovy.version>2.2.1</groovy.version>
<ivy.version>2.4.0</ivy.version>


 <build>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <configuration>
                            <!-- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/ -->
                            <source>1.6</source>
                            <target>1.6</target>
                            <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                                    <version>2.9.0-01</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <!-- 2.2.1 version isn't available as a release, so it needs to be acquired
                                    from the codehaus nexus repository -->
                            <dependency>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                                    <version>${groovy.version}-01-SNAPSHOT</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <!-- to allow @Grab annotations -->
                            <dependency>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.ivy</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>ivy</artifactId>
                                    <version>${ivy.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.1</version>
                    <executions>
                            <execution>
                                    <id>add-source</id>
                                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                            <sources>
                                                    <source>src/main/groovy</source>
                                            </sources>
                                    </configuration>
                            </execution>
```

I tried changing groovy version to 2.4.3 but got the same error. Anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: What Java are you using? http://www.groovy-lang.org/download.html#requirements

Comment: Both systems are on 1.7..

Comment: Change the `maven-compiler-plugin` to use source == target == 1.7.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - good thought, but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having just encountered a similar issue, I found that I had two issues:

## Maven deps that failed a download

A maven dependency (maven-assembly-plugin) had failed a download.

Deleting the `.lastUpdated` files in your local m2 repository:

```
#> find ~/.m2/repository -name *.lastUpdated
~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom.lastUpdated

#> find ~/.m2/repository -name *.lastUpdated -delete
```

## grapeConfig.xml & repository ssl certificate

Also your `~/.groovy/grapeConfig.xml` file needs to be configured to tell groovy where to pull the dependencies from - in my case it was from a corporate nexus repository, which also meant i had to install the https certificate in the JRE cacerts file.

### How to test

One suggestion to test you have everything set up correctly would be to call `grape install` on a test dependency and that will give you a clearer sense of what is wrong (grape is distributed as part of the groovy binaries, so include it on your path, or fully qualify its path):

```
grape install javax.mail mail 1.5.0-b01
```